# AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i'm trying to add a parameter of a model to a URL pattern, as such:

```
http://111.111.11.111:8080/resultados/image.jpg
```

where **nome_ficheiro = image.jpg** (nome_ficheiro is a model parameter, see below)

But i'm getting the following error:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/routers.py", line 139, in get_default_base_name
    assert queryset is not None, '`base_name` argument not specified, and could ' \
AssertionError: `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.
```

The URL pattern:

```
    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    urlpatterns = [url(r'^', include(router.urls))]
    router.register(r'resultados/(?P<nome_ficheiro>.+)/$',resultUploadView.as_view({'get': 'get_queryset'}))
```

The view:

```
class resultUploadView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = resultSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        nome = self.kwargs['nome_ficheiro']
        return labelResult.objects.filter(nome_ficheiro=nome)
```

The model:

```
 class labelResult(models.Model):
    nome_ficheiro   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    especie         = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    zona            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    data            = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

USING: Python 2.7.12 and DRF 3.6.3

EDITS:

urls.py:

```
router.register(r'results/(?P<nome_ficheiro>.+)/$', resultUploadView.as_view({'get': 'get_queryset'}), base_name='img_name')
```

still not working, getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

You may name the route when you add it:

```
router.register(
    r'the-url_pattern$',
    TheViewSet,
    base_name='put-something-here',
)
```

As an aside, it's strange to specify both `queryset` class attribute and `get_queryset` method, and this could be what was confusing DRF.  Pick one way or the other.

Comment: removed the qeryset as you seggested and added the base_name: router.register(r'results/(?P<nome_ficheiro>.+)/$', resultUploadView.as_view({'get': 'get_queryset'}), base_name='img_name')    but i keep getting the same error..

Comment: I think I see another problem, `router.register` expects a [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/), but you're passing a view.  Usually routers are used with viewsets, and views are just added as url instances directly to urlpatterns.  So, you should either change the view code to use viewsets, or keep the view as is and don't use the router.

Answer (score 1):

replace "base_name" to **"basename"**